# Creating VBA to populate information from a list into specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a phone list that I need help creating. Sheet 1 has the information being displayed. Sheet 2 has the Data.
I have 3 categories, Employees, Phone Numbers and Supervisors 
I have about 70 employees, (same with phone numbers) and about 6 supervisors

What I'm trying to do is When I key a supervisor on Sheet 1 they have blank cells under them and I want the employee that's keyed with that supervisor on sheet 2 put under the supervisor on sheet 1 in the next blank cell. Likewise with the phone number being keyed with the employee gets keyed in the adjacent cell next to the employee's name

On sheet 2 , column 1 is employee Column 2 is phone number and column 3 is supervisor

Is this possible to be accomplished? If so what would the VBA look like?

Thank you for any help and anyone stepping up to the challenge.

Comment: This is one of those "pictures are worth a thousand words" situations. It's very difficult to follow how your data looks and what you want it to look like. It sounds very doable though. In fact, it sounds like it can be done with a formula to pull the information into your blank cells i.e. `=INDEX(MATCH())`. If you put the Supervisor column first on Sheet2, then you could do this with a `=Vlookup()` (I think).

Comment: Yes that's possible.  If the Supervisor you "click" (key?) on Sheet1 has his/her name somewhere on sheet2 - along with his phone and address - then it is possible to do this.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the basic question, "What would it look like?"  You can either enter the supervisor's name manually, or use a pick list.  I'll assume manual entry.  You want a change event on sheet1, that looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("rngSupervisor") <> "" Then
        List_the_Subordinates
    Else
        Target.Worksheet.Range("A1").Select
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

When you enter the supervisor's name in A1 and press enter (or leave the cell), the change event is triggered.  This checks to see if data was entered in cell A1, and if so, it runs the subroutine "List_the_Subordinates."

Now, the subroutine to list the subordinates could be a for next loop, looking for the super's name and copying the subordinates' information over.  Something like this (very basic).

```
Sub List_the_Subordinates()
Dim sh1Bottom As Long, sh2Bottom As Long, rowCount As Long
Sheet2.Activate
'get bottom row of sheet 2
sh2Bottom = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheet1.Activate
sh1Bottom = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For rowCount = 1 To sh2Bottom
    If Sheet2.Cells(rowCount, 3) = Sheet1.Cells("A1") Then
        sh1Bottom = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheet1.Cells(sh1Bottom, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(rowCount, 1)
        Sheet1.Cells(sh1Bottom, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(rowCount, 2)
    End If
Next rowCount
End Sub
```

As I said, this is very basic.  Most people will tell you not to use activate and select if you can avoid it, but I have never figured out how to get the bottom row of the sheet without activating it :)  The for next loop is kind of brute force too.  You could use find or match or whatever, but since you have so few rows to deal with, this won't take long.

It's a place to start.  Play with it, and make it sing and dance for you.